# Erro Conversão String para Int

Tags: java

Estou fazendo um programinha simples, onde lê um arquivo .csv (Excel) e então gera um gráfico do mesmo. Porém estou tendo problemas na hora da conversão do String para o Int. Segue abaixo o codigo do evento do Botão:

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
  FileDialog abrir = new FileDialog(new Dialog(this),"Abrir arquivo",FileDialog.LOAD);
  abrir.setVisible(true);
  File arquivo = new File(abrir.getDirectory()+abrir.getFile());
  XYSeries temp = new XYSeries("Temperatura");

    try {
        String linhaDoArquivo;
        Scanner lerArquivo = new Scanner(arquivo);
        while(lerArquivo.hasNext()){
            linhaDoArquivo = lerArquivo.next();
            String[] valores = linhaDoArquivo.split(",");
            int instante = Integer.parseInt(valores[0]);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    XYSeriesCollection dataset = new XYSeriesCollection();
    dataset.addSeries(temp);

    JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart("Temperatura", "Instante", "Temperatura", dataset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false);

    ChartPanel panel = new ChartPanel(chart);
    jPanel1.removeAll();
    jPanel1.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    jPanel1.validate();

}
```

Comment: E qual é o problema?

Comment: Além de descrever o problema, seria interessante que você colocasse as 3 primeiras linhas do seu CSV. Pelo título da pergunta, você deve ter algo na primeira posição de alguma das linhas que gera exceção ao converter para inteiro.

Comment: Você debugou para ver o que tem na sua  `String[] valores` ?

Comment: Poste o Logger com o stacktrace da exceção para vermos qual é o erro que ocorre

Comment: Verifique se na primeira linha do seu CSV contém o cabeçalho do arquivo, provavelmente você está tentando converter este cabeçalho.

Comment: Desculpe a demora para responder, mas o erro estava no cabeçalho do csv mesmo, arrumei certinho e funcionou perfeitamente. Obrigado.

Comment: @MarcoAntonio, por favor poste a solução usada como resposta!

Answer (score 2):

Este código assume que o primeiro campo de cada linha do CSV é um inteiro:

```
        String[] valores = linhaDoArquivo.split(",");
        int instante = Integer.parseInt(valores[0]);
```

Porém é comum ter cabeçalhos no CSV com o título de cada coluna, o que causaria uma NumberFormatException:

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "ID"
>       at
>                   java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)

Então a solução é ajustar o CSV ou, ainda melhor, proteger o código:

```
String[] valores = linhaDoArquivo.split(",");

try {
      int instante = Integer.parseInt(valores[0]);
} catch (NumberFormatException e){
    //algo deu errado. Tratar aqui
    System.err.println(valores[0] + " não é numérico!");
}
```